# How to use special characters e.g. ¥, ‡ in the footer of a README.md file on GitHub to replace the default page numbering (1, 2, ...)?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

Can I please seek you help on how to use special characters e.g. ¥, §, ‡ in the footer of a README.md file on GitHub to replace the default numbering (1, 2, ...)?

I tried the following, but it is displaying the number '1' instead of the yen symbol '¥' which was my intended output.

```
*This has a footer[^&yen]*

[^&yen]: This is a footer content.
```

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub doesn't really give you a lot of control over how READMEs or other documents are rendered.  That's because choosing the punctuation marks for footnotes, just like choosing colours, fonts, or the size of text, is a style choice, and for consistency, security, and accessibility, GitHub doesn't let you change the style of documents it renders.  For example, CSS is not allowed at all, and generated HTML is filtered to remove anything potentially malicious.

If you want your document to be rendered in a different way, then you can use a renderer or toolchain which renders it in the way you want and then upload that document somewhere online, including to GitHub Pages, and then people can view it in the desired way.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204. This is new to me. Could you please share a few commonly used renderer or toolchain?

Comment: There are lots in various languages, but Jekyll and pandoc are two.